# Error sending email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sockets, smtp, sendmail, socketexception

I created a simple application at: [graficaromana.com.br](http://graficaromana.com.br/)

In the contact form (http://graficaromana.com.br/Contato) when I try to send an email I get an error.
Locally the mail is sent normally without any error.

Is there some setting I have to do on the host? in the domain?

**Error:**

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because
>   the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond 209.85.225.108:25

See the code for more details in link: https://gist.github.com/1149028

Comment: how are you sending mail? some details would be betters. there are many ways to send mail using smtp

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1149028  My controller and view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the remote host has maybe a separate server they use for sending mail out or that you have to be whitelisted with the host in order to send mail and a username and password may be required.  have not looked at your code but i see them kind of errors when there is a firewall involved and the machine trying to send does not have access through the firewall, as the firewall does not respond at all you get an answer like ' The server did not respond in a timely manner'   or 'the server did not respond after a certain amount of time'   i am assuming that before you posted on here that you have asked the hosting provider about sending mail, and what there preference is on how this should be carried out? right?

if so please provide info on what they have said

here is a sample of code to send email:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
var message = new MailMessage();
smtpClient.port = 25;
message.from = "test@test.com";
message.To.Add("me@workemail.com,client@office.com";
message.Subject = "Contact from website";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "<html><head></head><body>TEST</body></html>"

try { 
   smtpClient.Host = "relay.server.you.have.from.host";
   smtpClient.Send(message);
} catch( Exception ) {
   // host is down or we are local try other servers
   // here you can have more try / catch
   smtpClient.Host = "127.0.0.1"
   smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: i seen your code and i think maybe you have to use an alternative method or specifiy a host provider that allows outgoing SMTP from the localhost

Comment: They said they have to use a "relay server".

I do not know what this is or how to use.
The address they could give you is: "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"

Message 
In order to be able to send email through our hosting accounts that we offer you must use the following relay server in your code:

relay-hosting.secureserver.net

You do not need to provide a user name and password for this relay server as it does not require authentication.

Comment: okay you need to create an SmtpClient();  and smtpClient.Host is equal to the relay address the host has given you, it is best to set up a try / catch  so try the remote host if fails then its local code and 127.0.0.1

Comment: see amended post above put the code in a function like  public bool sendEmail(msg,to,from){}  hope it helps

Comment: First rrror
Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, relaying denied from your location [187.114.50.68] (#5.7.1)
Second error
Failure sending mail.

Comment: the first error is relay is only allowed when the code is on server not local, the second is probably your ISP and not been able to send email from your own host i.e yourself  use the code with the correct hostname of relay-hosting.secureserver.net  and you will find that the first error will go, as for the second change 127.0.0.1 to the same as your outgoing in your mail client providing you dont require a username and pass to send.